# angular-phonecat tutorial - web-server.js giving 404 errors with node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, http-status-code-404

Hi there I'm running through the angular phonecat tutorial but I'm stuck already on step-0 with the node.js http server returning 404's for /app/index.html

I do have other http servers installed on this box (Win7 Pro), but they aren't even running and I don't think I installed any of these as services either.

Where should I start looking to debug?

Here's the output so far:

```
C:\Users\S>node C:\Users\S\angular-phonecat\scripts\web-server.js
Http Server running at http://localhost:8000/
GET /app/index.html Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1636.2 Safari/537.36
404 Not Found: /app/index.html
GET /favicon.ico Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1636.2 Safari/537.36
404 Not Found: /favicon.ico
GET /app/index.html Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1636.2 Safari/537.36
404 Not Found: /app/index.html
```

Comment: you have to run the server being in the `angular-phonecat` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was fairly simple.  If you take a look at the instructions (windows users) at the end of the first page it says to only run executables from the windows command prompt, so on the next page where it says

"In a separate terminal tab or window, run node scripts\web-server.js to start the web server."

what they're really referring to is another Git Bash window that I'm guessing you'll need to leave running in the background for testing.

This is what your output should look like when you've successfully started the server:

```
user@windows-pc-name ~/angular-phonecat ((step-0))
$ node scripts/web-server.js
Http Server running at http://localhost:8000/
GET /app/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1636.2 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the command prompt and execute the `node scripts/web-server.js` with administrator access.

Answer (score 0):

After starting web sever with scripts\web-server.js command, open new browser window and give full path for "app/index.html" in that.

For example, If I have located angular-phonecat-master app in my Desktop directory then in browser window I will have to give following path:

localhost:8000/Desktop/angular-phonecat-master/angular-phonecat-master/app/index.html